# Synchronise Visual Studio Instances

Tags: visual-studio-2010, synchronization

Is there any tool or plugin that can synchronise visual studio so that when I use it at home the same windows are open in the same configuration as when I left work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Pepper](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/pepper-visual-studio-settings-synchronisation-backup-extension)?

Will sync (most of) your settings to the/ a cloud somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio Live Share](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/live-share/) may be able to be used to get this behaviour.